# Unable to print circle image in pdf using Codeigneiter + TCPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I am using [this](http://circle.firchow.net/) link for creating percentage basis circles on my views. It is working perfectly.

But when I convert this into my pdf then circle images are not displaying on my pdf. I am using [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org) library in my code.

Comment: please checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I Things it will solved your problem.

If you want to use design in **pdf** as you mentioned in question then

- you have to put `css` code inside html
- better to use inline `css`

**example**

```
$html='<html>
  <style>
    .test-div
    {
      width: 900px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color:green;
      color:yellow;

    }
  </style>
 <body>
   <div  class="test-div">
     vijay sharma
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>'
// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
```

so whatever `css` you used in that page put inside `style` tag then check

Suggestion : try to use `mpdf` library instead of `tcpdf`  its very simple to integrate ,use this link for more details [enter link description here](https://github.com/phpclicks/mpdf)